# Box mui material media query

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box, Button, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import '../fonts.css';

function Navbar() {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        width: '80%',
        height: '6vh',
        padding: '0 16px',
        margin: '0 auto',
        borderRadius: '2px',
        marginTop: '2%',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'left',
        gap: "20px",
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
            width: '100%',
            padding: '0 16px',
            marginTop: '0',
            borderRadius: '0',
        },
        background: 'radial-gradient(circle at center, #44627f 0%, #33465d 80%, #394d66 100%)',
        backgroundPosition: '60% 40%', // adjust position of background gradient
        backgroundSize: '110%',
      }}
    >
      {/* Navigation items */}
      <Typography variant="h6"
      sx = {{
        color: "white",
        fontFamily: 'main',
        fontSize: '18px',
        '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
            fontSize: "14px"
          },
      }}
      >
        element 3
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h6"
      sx = {{
        color: "white",
        fontFamily: 'main',
        fontSize: '18px',
        '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
            fontSize: "14px"
          },
      }}
      >
        element 2
    </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h6"
      sx = {{
        color: "white",
        fontFamily: 'main',
        fontSize: '18px',
        '@media (max-width: 600px)': {
            fontSize: "14px"
          },
      }}
      >
        element 1
    </Typography>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

The media query works for Typography but not for the Box component. I have no idea why.

Tried playing with the syntax or check maybe there is some other rule that causes that but didn't find any. Thing is it worked half an hour ago and just stopped suddenly. On dev tools if I inspect the element I can see the CSS changes but then again, nothing visual happens. Need help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Things don't just stop working. Can you back out the changes you've made over the last half hour (after saving your file obvs) and see what happened?

Answer (score 0):

The media query should indeed be working ([demo codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-artem-n8fmh1?file=/demo.tsx)). You likely aren't seeing anything visually because you only are switching the width from 80% --> 100% which may be hard to see since they aren't very different. In the demo I added a red border in the media query and you can see the styles are being applied.